# getting value in a runtime variable in oracle

Tags: oracle, variables

I want to get a value of a column into a runtime variable without declaring the variable.

Is it possible in oracle?

For Ex:- in mysql I can say

```
select 1 into @myvar;
```

Comment: `1` doesn't look much as a value of a column.

Comment: There are variables in SQL*Plus, and there are PL/SQL variables. Which are you talking about? (by the way, the answer for both is "no")

Answer (score 0):

If by `runtime variable` `in oracle`, you mean `substitution variable` `in SQL*Plus`, then you can do this:

```
SQL> column dummy new_value myvar
SQL> select dummy from dual;

D
-
X

1 row selected.

SQL> prompt &myvar
X
```